# Как настроить InMemory Security (Spring)

Tags: java, spring

Только изучаю Spring, покажите простой и легкий пример использования InMemory авторизацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При добавлении зависимости `spring-boot-starter-security` в pom.xml, по умолчанию вы будете иметь:

- in-memory авторизацию
- логин - `user`
- пароль случайный, который выводится в консоли при запуске приложения, например

`Using generated security password: 78fa095d-3f4c-48b1-ad50-e24c31d5cf35`

Для того, чтобы изменить логин/пароль необходимо указать `spring.security.user.name` и `spring.security.user.password` в application.properties.

Более подробно можно почитать в документации https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security.